# How do I move the archive.pst to a new location?

Tags: outlook

Currently the archive.pst is located in the Application Data Folder.

> c:\documents and Settings\username\local setting\application data\microsoft\outlook\

I would like to move it to a second hard disk (D:\archive).

WindowsXP sp3 \ Outlook 2003 sp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on the version, it may be that outlook upon startup asks you for the new location.

To play it safe, it can be copied to the new location, included as second personal folder, an then you remove the old personal folder.

Comment: After moving the file this is what happened.  Good call.

Answer (score 5):

Move the PST file to where you want it while outlook is not running, then launch outlook and do the following:

- Tools > Account Settings > Data Files
- Remove the PST file from Outlook
- Add a new data file and point it at
  the file in the new location

I think this should do what you want.

Comment: +1 This would probably work out great if lImbus' scenario did not take place.

Answer (score 3):

This Microsoft Support article explains how to do that:

[How to set the location of an archive .pst file in Outlook](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B836755&)

> This article describes how to set the location of the Microsoft Outlook archive personal folders (.pst) file by modifying the Outlook profile file (.prf).
>
> There are two methods that you can use
>   to set the location of the archive.pst file. The first method uses the
>   Microsoft Office 2003 Custom
>   Installation Wizard (CIW) to create
>   the .prf file. The second method shows
>   you how to create a basic .prf file
>   that includes a custom setting for the
>   archive.pst file.

Comment: More recent version: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179062.aspx It would help if it were possible to modify existing profiles, though (mass replacement of paths via script).

Answer (score 2):

1. Shut down Outlook (2007)
2. Copy archive.pst to a new location
3. Rename first archive.pst to be unfindable by Outlook. I renamed mine ~archive.old.
4. Restart Outlook.

I had my archive folders open when I shut down. Don't know if that matters. When Outlook restarted it said it couldn't find the archive (Personal Folders) file, and showed an Open File dialog. I selected the new file. Outlook then reported my Archive as being in the new location with all other Archive settings intact.